# PostgreSQL group by two columns in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table with different sport modalities and the nationality of the players.

```
CREATE table test
(
    column01 VARCHAR(255),
    column02 VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO test VALUES('soccer', 'brazilian');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('soccer', 'brazilian');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('soccer', 'argentinian');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('cycling', 'american');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('cycling', 'colombian');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('cycling', 'colombian');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('cycling', 'colombian');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('bascketball', 'american');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('bascketball', 'american');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('bascketball', 'french');
INSERT INTO test VALUES('bascketball', 'spanish');
```

I would like to get a result group by the number of the same modalities and the nationalities of each one. Something like this:

```
column01 | column02
---------+----------
    3    |     2
    4    |     2
    4    |     3
```

Comment: Please define "modalities".

Comment: @GordonLinoff done... sport modalities. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select count(*), count(distinct column2)
from t
group by column1;
```